# winston: Attempt to write logs with no transports - using default logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I followed a tutorial to set up winston (2.x) default logger in my express app. When updating to the current version of winston (3.0.0) I have a problem with adding the transports. I have followed the [latest docs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-the-default-logger) but still I get the notice in console and no log files are created at all:

> [winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports

*logging.js*

```
const winston = require('winston');

module.exports = function () {

  const files = new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' });
  const myconsole = new winston.transports.Console();

  winston.add(myconsole);
  winston.add(files);

}
```

*index.js*

```
const winston = require('winston');
...

require('./logging');
winston.info("Give some info");
```

> [winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports
>   {"message":"Give some info","level":"info"}

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had a similar issue.  If I recall correctly, I had to call the requirement as a function in my index.js.

```
require('./logging')();
```

Answer (score 23):

In winston 3 you need to create a `logger` object, then add `transport`s to it.

Winston 3 has many [examples](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/tree/master/examples), but to adapt from the [readme](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), do something like this:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' })
  ]
});

logger.info('it works!!');
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the usage of `winston.createLogger`. The readme states using "your own logger" as the recommended way. Nevertheless I would rather prefer to use the "default logger" which is also listed within the [readme](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-the-default-logger). Unfortunately, when using `winston.configure()` there is still the same notice in console as described in my original question.

Comment: That may be a bug worth opening a GH issue for.  There are still some kinks with the 3.0 release that are being worked on, this may be one of them.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the default logger in winston v3 then you simply have to add this piece of code in your main file

```
const winston = require('winston')

winston.add(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' }))
```

Comment: Hope it helps out someone new who might come across this error as of late